# django: Better implementation of LEFT JOIN

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models,

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    post_title = models.CharField()
    post_type = models.CharField() 

class Comments(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="post_comments")
    comment = models.CharField()
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get "all" posts with post_type "blog" along with comments of a specific user. If am doing it with raw query, the query will be like this,

```
SELECT p.id as post_id, p.post_title, pc.comment 
FROM Post p 
LEFT JOIN Comments pc ON (p.id=pc.post AND pc.user_id=20)
WHERE p.post_type='blog'
```

The above query will return all posts with post_type as "blog" along with comments by user_id 20. How can I implement this using Post objects filter in django?

I tried the bellow method, But it didnt work.

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(post_type='blog', post_comments__user_id=20).all()
```

I googled a lot but I couldnt find a good solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you had a look at this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships ?

You can see what raw sql django runs if you print:
`str(Post.objects.filter(post_type='blog', post_comments__user_id=20).query)`

My guess is you will need to use this:
`Post.objects.filter(post_type='blog').filter(post_comments__user_id=20)`

Comment: I dont want to print the query, I want to get the data using django objects filter way.

Comment: I understand, you can print the query for debugging purposes, see what sql django generates using that filter.

Comment: It prints the inner join query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all `post_type` as "blog" and `comments` with `user_id 20` then you can do this query

```
from django.db.models import Q

Post.objects.filter(Q(post_type='blog') | Q(post_comments__user_id=20))
```